# advanced filters in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In my case, I have to filter the data by city or institute

I have two tables like below

```
 Institutes table

 id  |  institute_name |  phoneNumber
 -------------------------------------
  1      infocampus         9999999999
 -------------------------------------
  2      jspider            2348234982

 courses table

 id  |   institute_id    |     course_name
 ------------------------------------------
 1             1                 java
 2             1                 php
```

Relations that I have created

```
Institue model

public function courses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Course::class);
}

Course model

public function institute()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(Institute::class);
}
```

I have tried with below code

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    $institute = (new Institute)->newQuery();

    // Search for a user based on their institute.

    if ($request->has('institute_name')) {
    $institute->where('institute_name', $request->input('institute_name'));
    }

    // Search for a user based on their course_name.

    if ($request->has('course_name')) {
    $institute->whereHas('courses', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('courses.course_name', $request->input('course_name'));
    });
    }

    return response()->json($institute->get());
}
```

From above i able to filter the data but it show only institution table data like below

```
[
{
    "id": 2,
    "institute_name": "qspider",
    "institute_contact_number": "9903456789",
    "institute_email": "qspider@gmail.com",
    "status": "1",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}
]
```

but what I need is when I do seach with course_name or instute_name I need to fetch data from institue table as well as courses table data.
Can anyone help on this, please?

Comment: Do you want to use filter institute_name and course_name together or independent?

Comment: use relationships. In your case each institute has many courses

Comment: hello @VenkataKrishna I have used has many relationships

Comment: hello @akbansa it depends on user he can filter together or independent.

Comment: Define all the tables like what is the relationship between user, institute and courses tables

Comment: It show data like that only until you specifically write $institute->courses or anything like whichever you mentioned in relationship

Comment: @Manjunath You're using Institute model in filter() not User model

Comment: @ Venkata Krishna I have edited question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following it should return the institutes with the courses.

```
$institute->with(['courses' => function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('courses.course_name', $request->input('course_name'));
}])
```

Comment: hello @Saad no it didn't work, getting an error mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given